# Sencha Filter Grid column

Tags: extjs, filter, filtering

I am trying find out how to filter the column so to find a specif floor value (or e.g. all the floors with the value "2") and sort them in ascending/descending numerical order by clicking on the specific button.
I wrote this code but it is not working, because when I write a value in the filter he give me no rows (also if I try to use "type:'string'"):

```
{
   text: "Floor",
   dataIndex: 'attributes',
   filter:{
       type: 'number',
       value : 'floor'
   },
   renderer: function (value) {
      return value['floor'];
   },
```

}

[image]

[image]

How should I change my code to make it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `dataIndex` to not nested column.

You can add logic field in model like:

```
 {
    name: "floor", "mapping": "attributes.floor"
}
```

And in columns:

```
{
   text: "Floor",
   dataIndex: 'floor',
   filter:{
       type: 'number'
   }
}
```

Edited - check out the fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/30gr

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Fiddle', 'Welcome to Sencha Fiddle!');

        var store = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
            fields: [{
                "name": "name",
                "type": "string"
            }, {
                "name": "floor",
                "mapping": function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data && data.attributes && Ext.isNumber(data.attributes.floor)) {
                        return data.attributes.floor;
                    }
                    return null
                }
            }],
            data: [{
                "name": "A1",
                "attributes": {
                    "floor": 1
                }
            }, {
                "name": "B1",
                "attributes": {
                    "floor": 1
                }
            }, {
                "name": "A2",
                "attributes": {
                    "floor": 2
                }
            }, {
                "name": "A3",
                "attributes": {
                    "floor": 3
                }
            }, {
                "name": "ANU",
                "attributes": {
                    "floor": null
                }
            }, {
                "name": "AN"
            }]
        });

        Ext.create("Ext.grid.Panel", {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            width: 400,
            height: 500,
            store: store,
            columns: [{
                "dataIndex": "name",
                "text": "Name"
            }, {
                "dataIndex": "floor",
                "text": "Floor"
            }]
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! now it works. Only with the Sort Ascending/Descending I have still problem

Comment: Check the fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/30gr

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to calculate the floor's value in the data model instead of using column renderer. So that you can filter and sort on that value.

You need to add a calculated field on your Model

```
fields: [{
    name: 'attributes'
}, {
    name: 'floor',
    calculate: function(data) {
        return data.attributes && Number(data.attributes.floor);
    }
}]
```

Then your column becomes

```
{
    text: "Floor",
    dataIndex: 'floor',
    filter:{
        type: 'number',
        value : 'floor'
    }
}
```

Comment: Your field example arent working. `Field floor depends on undefined field attributes`

Comment: You are wrong @norbeq. My code is working fine, also with sorting: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/30h3

Comment: In my case the solution is in the middle: to make it sortable correctly I had to edit my code like this :                                                                                     
       `name: "floor",
       calculate: function (data) {
          if(Number(data.attributes.floor)){
              return Number(data.attributes.floor)
          }else{
            return null;
          }
      }`

Comment: Look what is done with no floor passed : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/30h8 is rendered like 0 - so is bad.